# transition of ordinary matrix is a invertible matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $ A,B  \in M(n,R)$and $A$,$B$ both are not equal to zero matrice, does there exist infinite $x\in R$ such that $A+xB \in GL(n,R)$?

Or  only there exist finite $x\in R$ such that $A+xB \notin GL(n,R)$?

Comment: Well, if $A$ and $B$ are zero matrix...

Comment: Does $GL(n,\Re)$ denote the set of all invertable $n\times n$ real matrices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a partial answer for invertible $A$:

Since $A+ xB = xA ({1 \over x}I+A^{-1}B)$, we see that $A+ xB$ is invertible
**iff** ${1 \over x} \notin \sigma(A^{-1}B) \cap \mathbb{R}$.

Hence the values of $x$ for which
$A+ xB $ is not invertible is given by the number of distinct real eigenvalues of $A^{-1}B$.

Comment: if A is a singular matrix?

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought both $A,B$ were invertible.

Answer (score 2):

I below show an example of $A, B \in M(n, \Re)$ where there **doesn't** exist any $x$ such that 
$$
A + xB \in GL(n, \Re)
$$

Let $n \geq 3$ and $\text{rank}(A) = \text{rank}(B) = 1$, thus $\text{rank}(xB) = 1$ for $x \neq 0$ and when $x = 0$, $\text{rank}(xB) = 0$. Therefore,
$$
\text{rank}(A + xB) \leq \text{rank}(A) + \text{rank}(xB) \leq 2
$$
$A + xB$ is not of full rank, thus is not invertible.